# Generalizing a hypothesis when possible

Tags: coq

Suppose I have a goal of the form

```
forall x, A x -> B x -> P
```

where `x` does not occur free in `P` (the bound `x` is not involved in the conclusion). By doing `intros` here, I will get three separate hypotheses in my proof:

```
x : nat
H0 : A x
H1 : B x
===============
P
```

But I need to strengthen my hypotheses and get the following.

```
H0 : forall x, A x -> B x
===============
P
```

so that I can instantiate `x` to whatever I need.

Since `x` does not occur in `P`, it is logically valid to have

```
(forall x, A x -> B x -> P) -> ((forall x, A x -> B x) -> P)
```

My question is, how can I do this in Coq?

Comment: Are you saying `forall (T : Type) (A B : T -> Prop) (P : Prop),
      (forall x, A x -> B x -> P) -> (forall x, A x -> B x) -> P.` is provable? Then there is a counter-example: use `A` equal to `fun _ => False`. `(forall x, A x -> B x)` would still hold, but you won't be able to recover `P` from the first premise, because it's saying that if for any `x` you can prove `A x` and `B x` then you get `P`, but you cannot prove `A x` in this case (it's `False`).

Comment: Ok, I see your point. In my case, though, I know there is at least one `x` for which `A x` holds.

Comment: So, I know I could go ahead and prove the last statement of my question above as a Lemma and then use that Lemma in my main proof, but my question is whether there is any tactic that helps with strengthening hypotheses in this way (as there are techniques for getting your desired induction hypothesis)?

Comment: I think it's better to post a self-contained example a.k.a [mcve]. I mean the point of using a proof assistant is to be (excruciatingly) precise, so to give a precise answer we need a precise question.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I'll follow your advice and create a separate question later in the day.

Comment: Don't you mean you want `(forall x, A x /\ B x) -> P`?

Answer (score 3):

As Anton pointed out, we need some more context to understand what you are trying to do.  Nevertheless, here are some ideas that might help you.

You first asked how to get from a context like this

```
x  : nat
H1 : A x
H2 : B x
```

to a context like this

```
H : forall x' : nat, A x' -> B x'
```

There is no way of accomplishing that for every `A` and `B`, even if you know that `A` is valid for some number.  For instance, suppose that `A x` means "`x` is even", and `B x` means "`x` is zero"; that is,

```
A x := exists y, x = 2 * y
B x := x = 0
```

The only information that the first set of hypotheses gives you is that `x` is zero.   The second set of hypotheses, however, is contradictory, because it asserts that every even number is equal to zero. Since you cannot add contradictory hypotheses from consistent ones, you cannot go from the first context to the second.

There are, of course, other cases where going from one context to the other is possible: if you manage to prove `forall x', A x' -> B x'` assuming that `A x` and `B x` hold for some `x`.  For this, you need the `assert` tactic.  If you execute

```
assert (H : forall x', A x' -> B x').
```

Coq will generate two subgoals: one where you have to prove `forall x', A x' -> B x'` given your previous hypotheses, and another one where the context gets a new hypothesis `H : forall x', A x' -> B x'`.